# Only one seed not working Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-seeding

all seeds are working but one throws exception

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::setContainer()

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('lang')->insert([
        [
            'lang_name' => 'Русский'
        ],
        [
            'lang_name' => 'English'
        ],
        [
            'lang_name' => 'Empty'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing the Seeder class name to something else? Like LangSeeder ? And not Lang?

Looks like Lang is a class name used by Laravel already and seeder classes are in root namespace!

Comment: <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class Lang extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('lang')->insert([
            [
                'lang_name' => 'Русский'
            ],
            [
                'lang_name' => 'English'
            ],
            [
                'lang_name' => 'Empty'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}

Comment: Hey, can you try changing the Seeder class name to something else? Like LangSeeder ? And not Lang?

Looks like Lang is a class name used by Laravel already and seeder classes are in root namespace!